# How to know the client Url in WSO2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am getting messages from Proxy client how could i know client url means i want to do a filter condition based on url so in that case i could know that which url hitting me
i have tried with some sample code nut its notworking my code like this

```
<property name="client_url" expression="get-property('From')"/>
```

and also i logged it but its not returning null log is like this

```
LogMediator To: /services/RoleDetails, MessageID: urn:uuid:695faeb5-b26e-405d-ab7b-ce27213f5cbe, Direction: request, client_url = null
```

same thing working for

```
<property name="client_url" expression="get-property('To')"/>
```

Log for his

```
LogMediator To: /services/RoleDetails, MessageID: urn:uuid:a550ba76-201d-48c8-b069-3afdbb2b2db1, Direction: request, client_url = /services/RoleDetails
```

how could i know the client uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You need to set 'From' property from your client.

But you can do something like this.

```
 <property name="from property------->" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
```

and

```
<property name="from property------->" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_HOST')"/>
```

Comment: i wish to know the service name which service hitting me based on that only i could manage my sequence above To property is working From is not working ..

Comment: What do you mean by client service or service name at client side? Can you give an example?

Comment: i have one proxy i wish to allow use my present proxy only that proxy which is implemented by me ..client may be same machine else other if same i will do as per your guidance but my issue is i want filter based on the URL not based on the IP address . i am trying with From but returning null..

Answer (score 0):

you have to get that from axis2 context. refer this [post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/11/retriving-clientiphost-within-sequence.html)

Comment: its giving ip address ..but my issue is i need client service name why because i wish allow that service to access my sequence ...how could i know it above To property working fine but From property giving null

Comment: 'To' points where the messgae is targeted to send.'from' header says where that message is coming from? are you setting that header from your client? if you dont set , you wont get that inside esb..But you can identify the remote-host/ip properties as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But i think your mediation logic is wrong,..doing a filter based on 'from' address is right?..are you going to allow only single client to  send msg?

Comment: what do u imagine its absolute right i wish to allow only one single proxy to my implemented proxy ..i have done using From but its not working its giving null

Comment: You can restrict the access using IP..Or else, as i said earlier your client has to set the 'FROM' ehader